# onclick event is occuring two times in iPhone hybrid app

Tags: javascript, ios, dom-events

I am developing a iPhone Hybrid App. In that I have inserted a link using Javascript and defined the function that should be called on `onclick` event.

When I click the link function is called and required action is performed but after that if I click anywhere in the body of the app the same function is called again.

This is happening for both the two links present in my App.

Can anyone tell what wrong is happening ?

I have written a function to add an image as a link. Code is given below:

```
// create a link for delete enquiry
var DelLink = document.createElement("a");

// setting the name of the link.
DelLink.setAttribute("name" , "DelButton"+pCurrentEnquiryID);

// image for the delete and its properties.
var DelImage = document.createElement("img");
DelImage.setAttribute("src","images/delete.png");
DelImage.setAttribute("height","30px");
DelImage.setAttribute("width","30px");

// append image to the link
DelLink.appendChild(DelImage);

//specifying onclick event of the link
DelLink.setAttribute("onclick","DeleteEnquiry(this)");
//DelLink.onclick = "DeleteEnquiry(this)";

return DelLink;
```

Comment: I have a couple of idea's of what happens here (_touch_ devices don't have a _click_ event as such, but a _touchstart_ and _touchend_ event), but you're going to _have_ to show some code

Comment: you can think it as a web page and javascript code I have used is something like this  ....... link.setAttribute("onclick","Somefuncton(this)");

Comment: I think you have troubles with markdown: insert four spaces before each line of a paragraph (the copy&pasted code) to display the paragraph as a literal code. If you want to display some code, escape with backticks.

Comment: I can think whatever I like, but I can't help unless I can _see_ what code is causing your problem. I could, for instance, assume your code looks like this: `document.getElementById('foo').onclick = function(e){ console.log('bar');}` or `document.body.addEventListener('click',function(e){console.log('foo'),false);` or `<a href="#" onclick="javascript:return console.log(this);">Foo</a>` or... to `Infinity`. Please, some code might help narrowing this down

Comment: `link.setAttribute("onclick","Somefuncton(this)");` should only trigger one event per click. Also note that the `onclick` attribute shouldn't be used. Use `addEventListener("click", somefunction)` instead.

Comment: I have tried the addEventListener() method also but it is giving same problem

Comment: Show us *all* code. The code you posted doesn't cause the issue.

Comment: Note that you should edit the question to add more details, you don't need to rely on the comment section.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so you're setting the `onclick` attribute. Now this works perfectly well on *"traditional"* platforms (that have a mouse-like device with buttons that can be used to click on objects). A touch device (clue is in the name) doesn't have this, instead it is operated by touching the screen. Allright, you knew that, so I take it you can understand that the `touch` event is *extremely* overloaded (multi-touch).

Touching the screen for a second means something completely different than touching the screen for a split second. You can also touch the screen with 1, 2, 3 or 4 fingers. Each time this is to be processed differently. 
To make things even more complex, you can *drag* or *swipe* accross the screen, which needs to be handled differently, too.

As luck would have it, I've recently written some code to map certain touch events to a click handler, using closures, binding listeners and setting timeouts all over the place. So this might help you on your way:

```
if ('ontouchstart' in window)
{//we have a touch device
    document.body.addEventListener('touchstart',function(e)
    {//handle all touch events on the body
        e = e || window.event;
        //not sure about all mobile browsers (win mobile)
        //so I'm playing it safe
        var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
        if (target.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'a')
        {//didn't touch on a link
            return e;//stop
        }
        //touch must end after .3 seconds, otherwise user is zooming or something
        var timer = setTimeout(function()
        {
            target.removeEventListener('touchend',endHandler,false);//unbind after .3 seconds
            clearTimeout(timer);
        },300);
        var endHandler = function(e)
        {
            e = e || window.event;
            var endTarget = e.target || e.srcElement;//get element on which the touch ended
            clearTimeout(timer);//stop timer
            target.removeEventListener('touchend',endHandler,false);//remove listener
            if (endTarget !== target)
            {//user "swiped"
                return e;
            }
            //touch ended within .3 seconds, and ended on the same element, interpret this as click
            return clickHandlerFunction.apply(target,[e]);//invoke click handler with the target as context
        };
        target.addEventListener('touchend',endHandler,false);//bind touchend listener
    },false);
}
```

What this does, basically, is register *all* touchstart events. The first thing that is being checked is *did the user touch on an element of interest*, one which I want to handle with my custom event handler. If not, the event is returned, nothing changes. 
If the element touches is of interest, I create a listener for a `touchend` event on that target. I also set a timeout, which will remove that listener after .3 seconds (to prevent leaks). If the `touchend` event fires, check if the user was released on the original element, if not, interpret this as a swipe, and stop.
If the targets match, invoke the click handler, in the target's context and *pass the event object!* so you can invoke `stopPropagation()` and/or `preventDefault()` methods. The `touchhandler` also kicks off by clearing the timer and removes itself, too (again: to prevent mem leaks).
As ever, this is a really, really basic snippet that can do with a lot more work

The touch events contain a lot more info (you can check how many fingers are touching the screen, for instance). I omitted a bit of my original code, too because that would have made it *very* complex and messy (and I don't have it here with me, and I can't really remember how I dealt with certain situations). I can tell you, however, that I tend to check the `e.clientX` and `e.clientY` coordinates, and if the `touchend` event was within 50px of the `touchstart` target I map it to the click handler anyway: to provide some *soft focus* for people who are cold and trembling ;) so even Inuit can browse the page.

Anyhow, see what works for you. A couple of useful links though:
[Touch table](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/tableTouch.html)
[some history](http://www.scribd.com/doc/56583964/Touch-Events-Mobile-Web-Development)
[some touch libs](https://github.com/bebraw/jswiki/wiki/Touch)

Comment: I have used 'touchup' event instead of 'click' this solves problem for one of the link but for other link its giving weird behaviour i.e. function is called even before page is loaded

Comment: `touchup` is far from reliable (check the first link: touch table), and is primarily meant to register _"longer touches"_, you need to register _"tab"_ events. I'd say `touchstart` and `touchend` are the more reliable and X-mobile-browser compatible events in this case